# Drupal PHPUnit tests taking more than a day to execute

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm currently building Drupal inside a container, enabling the modules(using drush) and running testcases for the modules. I have ran the testcases for module [facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/) using the vendor/phpunit cli command but its taking more than 30 hours for me. Any idea why its taking so much time?

```
bash-4.4# ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ../modules/facets/tests/src/
PHPUnit 9.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning:       Your XML configuration validates against a deprecated schema.
Suggestion:    Migrate your XML configuration using "--migrate-configuration"!

Testing /home/server/drupal/modules/facets/tests/src
EEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  63 / 332 ( 18%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.... 126 / 332 ( 37%)
......................E........................................ 189 / 332 ( 56%)
............................................................... 252 / 332 ( 75%)
............................................................... 315 / 332 ( 94%)
.................                                               332 / 332 (100%)


Time: 31:58:29.066, Memory: 30.00 MB
```

PS: I tried testing using the [simpletest](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpletest) module, but its only testing 80 testcases(instead of 332 as above). Also, I want to use the cli for my work, not gui

Comment: I have no idea about Drupal, I am a Laravel ddv, but have you tried running each file instead of everything at once ? If you do or did, can you pinpoint which one is taking too much time ? If not, do all the test (each one) take more than 5 or 10 seconds ? Are they simple ? Can you share the most complex test ?

Comment: I did monitor the execution of these testcases using nohup and tail commands, each testcase is taking a significant amount of time(> 30mins atleast). I'll try running individual testcases. You can find the test cases here - https://git.drupalcode.org/project/facets/-/tree/8.x-1.x/tests/src

Comment: Can you point me to any test that takes a really long time ? There are a lot of tests and I have no idea about it.